# Symfony getparameter in kernel

Tags: symfony

I try to get my getParameter when i call my kernel :

```
//$this->_kernel = new \AppKernel("dev", true);
    $this->_kernel = new \AppKernel($this->_container->getParameter('env'), true);
    $this->_kernel->boot();
    $this->_container = $this->_kernel->getContainer();
    $this->_logger    = $this->_container->get('logger.common');
```

But that return null because i use getparameter before to create my container.
How i can do get my 'env' when i call this new appkernel ?

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need your environment in that way. If you take a look at your `AppKernel.php` there are bundles only activated if you are in dev.

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'])) {
    $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
    $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
    $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
    $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
}
```

So there is a function `$this->getEnvironment`.

Comment: Thank you, but for use this function, i need to call my kernel before.
So i can't call getenvironement in when i create my kernel, like this : $this->_kernel = new \AppKernel($this->_kernel->getEnvironment(), true);

Comment: No take a look at your `app.php` file. There you define the env for the kernel. Before that you have no Kernel to load a config variable. That make no sense... that is the first Entry Point for your application. Why do you need such a structure?